# Cordova request forwarding proxy

Tags: cordova, phonegap

Hi I have an angular app that I've written that gets all the data from the server by reaching the `/api` url.

For example:
`https://localhost:4200/api/families`

When developing in Angular I was able to map the `/api` path to the actual server (in my case `localhost:3000/api`) - I do that using proxy settings in the angular.json file

When deploying it to the web I use one server, that serves the static pages from the root, and the `/api` returns the `api` data.

This works great, doesn't require CORS and is generally pretty cool.

But now I want to deploy my app as a native app using `cordova` and I can't find the configuration to ask cordova to forward all requests to `/api` to another url.

There are similar settings, with Angular cli, react, and even vue.

In angular, it's called `proxying to a backend server`

https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server

Answer (score -1):

This is how i did port forwarding. https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/local-server

Basically you need to set up forwarding from your phone to localhost using chrome . When I did it, I had my phone connected via cable.

Comment: It's not what I was looking for, since I was looking for port forwarding for production, not just dev - and I'm looking for a cordova plugin/feature to do that